# Determine if an internet connection is available

Tags: xml, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

) I make the download of an xml file from the internet to the memory phone.. I want to see if the internet connection is available to make the download and send a message if not. And if not i want to see if the xml file as already present in the memory.. if present, the appliccation doesn't make the download.

I have the following code:

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri xmlUri = new Uri("http://dl.dropbox.com/file_xml.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Downloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(xmlUri);




    }

    void Downloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the xml-file");
        }
        else
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();


                using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("xml_file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
                {
                    string xml_file = e.Result.ToString(); 
                    writeFile.WriteLine(xml_file);
                    writeFile.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() method can tell you this:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
...
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    // do network-bound stuff
}
else
{
    // notify the user that there is no network connection
}
```

Comment: What crazy kind of naming scheme results in `GetIsNetworkAvailable()`!?

Comment: Its called like that because the result can take 30seconds (if i remember correctly) to response. So its not instant.

Comment: Caution because it's not very reliable, if you enter a subway station by example this methods can return true for a long time.